# Facebook Integration Session Issue

Tags: facebook

Here is my UserLogin.aspx Page code, which contains authentication of Facebook user, the problem is i am maintaing token in session which i laterly use it on Default.aspx. if you see the line Session["facebook_token"] = authToken;

On my Default.aspx page load i have placed this code, but it gives me null value, when i go to home or default page.

```
    if (Session["facebook_token"] != null)
        lblUserName.Text = Session["facebook_token"].ToString();


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using SocialMediaModel;
using Facebook.Components;

public partial class UserLogin : System.Web.UI.Page
{
FacebookService _fbService = new FacebookService();
private const string FACEBOOK_API_KEY = "551810942508804";
private const string FACEBOOK_SECRET = "b63b8cca428b42935e6eab59976367b1";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ApplicationKey and Secret are acquired when you sign up for
    _fbService.ApplicationKey = FACEBOOK_API_KEY;
    _fbService.Secret = FACEBOOK_SECRET;
    _fbService.IsDesktopApplication = false;

    string sessionKey = Session["facebook_session_key"] as String;
    string userId = Session["facebook_userId"] as String;

    string authToken = Request.QueryString["auth_token"];

    Session["facebook_token"] = authToken;

    // We have already established a session on behalf of this user
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionKey))
    {
        _fbService.SessionKey = sessionKey;
        _fbService.UserId = userId;
    }
    // This will be executed when facebook login redirects to our page
    else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(authToken))
    {
        _fbService.CreateSession(authToken);
        Session["facebook_session_key"] = _fbService.SessionKey;
        Session["facebook_userId"] = _fbService.UserId;
        Session["facebook_session_expires"] = _fbService.SessionExpires;
    }
    // Need to login
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect(@"http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=" +   
       _fbService.ApplicationKey + @"&v=1.0");
    }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> `string authToken = Request.QueryString["auth_token"];`
>
> `Session["facebook_token"] = authToken;`

Looks like you are executing these lines on every page load(?) – without checking if there even *is* a GET parameter by this name.